# Making or Predefining Structure of Nested Dictionary/JSON || Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, collections, nested

Input: I have Excel file containing 3 columns and format of excel file is like as follow:

```
A   C   D
A   C   E
A   F   G
B   H   J
B   H   K
A   F   I
B   L   M
B   L   N
A   F   O
```

I wish to make dictionary from the above input in below format:
Output:

```
dictionary= {'A':{'C':['D','E'],'F':['G','I','O']},'B':{'H':['J','K'],'L':['M','N']}}
```

Logic: For each distinct column-1 value, need to make nested dictionary & in that nested part, for each distinct column-2 value, need to make list of correspondingly column-3 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Edchum 
@MYGz
Thanks!! But without using pandas, i ended by doing something like this.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from nested_dict import nested_dict

book = open_workbook(input_file_location) # location of excel file 
sheet_3=book.sheets()[2] #sheet_3 in which i have data
data_sheet_3  = [sheet_3.row_values(i) for i in xrange(sheet_3.nrows)] # getting data of sheet-3
# specifying 2-level of nesting
#format of dictionary: {'Key1':{'Key2':['Value1','value2']},'Key3':{'Key4':['Value3','value4']}} 
dictionary=nested_dict(2,list) 
for row_no in xrange(sheet_3.nrows):
        col_1=data_sheet_3[row_no][0]
        col_2=data_sheet_3[row_no][1]
        col_3=data_sheet_3[row_no][2]
        dictionary[col_1][col_2].append(col_3)

print dictionary
```

## nested_dict(2,list) is the main important point in the code which allowed me to specify two levels of nesting.

If you find anything better or alternative of Pre-defining the structure of nested dictionary in python, please share with example.

Comment: Good. You can use defaultdict as well.

Comment: @MYGz,  Can u please write code for defaultdict. As i know only one level of nesting using default dict. 1) from collections import defaultdict  2) dictionary=defaultdict(list)    ..   It would create {'KEY':[Value,value1,value2]}.  Please share the code for above question by using default dict/ dict.setdefault().  Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('excel_file', header=None)
d = {}
for b in df.groupby([0,1])[2].apply(list).to_frame().iterrows():
    if b[0][0] not in d:
        d[b[0][0]] = {b[0][1]: b[1].tolist()[0]}
    else:
        d[b[0][0]][b[0][1]] = b[1].tolist()[0]
print d
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'C': ['D', 'E'], 'F': ['G', 'I', 'O']}, 'B': {'H': ['J', 'K'], 'L': ['M', 'N']}}
```

Comment: @EdChum,  i ended by doing something without pandas. nested_dict worked here. Please check code as new answer!!