# How to grouping and transform in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Now I have below dataframe

```
A B C
1 1 1 
1 2 1
1 3 2
2 4 2
2 5 2
2 6 3
```

I would like to grouping by df.A, and sum up in df.B

But, I would like to transform C as first of each group elements.

So I would like to get results below.

```
A B  C
1 6  1
2 15 2
```

How I can remain df.C and transform the first element of each group?

I tried df.groupby(A)[B].sum() but I couldnt figure out next step...

Comment: thank you for cooperation! I accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns) and pass a dict of funcs to perform on the cols of interest:

```
In [115]:
df.groupby('A').agg({'B':'sum','C':'first'}).reset_index()

Out[115]:
   A  C   B
0  1  1   6
1  2  2  15
```

The dict has the col name and the func to perform on each col, here we can pass the string name of the func for [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first).

To reorder the cols you can use fancy indexing:

```
In [116]:
df.groupby('A').agg({'B':'sum','C':'first'}).reset_index().ix[:,df.columns]

Out[116]:
   A   B  C
0  1   6  1
1  2  15  2
```

Comment: how does the columns rearrange in order in the second method.

Comment: @MYGz `ix[:,df.columns]` here `ix` takes `:` for all rows, but it will re-order the columns to the order of the columns passed, here it orders the output to the original df column order

Comment: Ah. Got it. Groupby will create a new df object then?

Comment: `groupby` is just an object that describes how the grouping should be performed, only when you call some method or aggregation does it then perform the operation and return a Series or DataFrame as appropriate

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871053/making-or-predefining-structure-of-nested-dictionary-json-python#41871053

Comment: I am stuck on this: `df.groupby([0,1], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: [q for q in x.iloc[:,2]])`

Comment: @MYGz I think for that you need `df.groupby([0,1])[2].apply(list).to_frame()` and then iterate row-wise to build up the dict, the to `to_frame` allows you to call a func row-wise on the df

Comment: Finally got it :D. Thanks for the Tip :) If you have a more elegant solution then do post and ping me.